# Styling a text that is too long

Tags: html, css

Below is a visual presentation of my dilemma[image]:

You have a list that is inserted in a sidebar, I would want that if the line is too long than the second line align itself properly as shown above.

Below is the code:

```
//getting the providers
function getProviders(){

            if(isset($_GET['user_query']))
    {
                  $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];
    global $con;
    $get_providers = "select DISTINCT course_provider from courses where (course_title like '%$search_query%' ) AND course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 5";
    $run_providers = mysqli_query($con, $get_providers);

    while ($row_providers=mysqli_fetch_array($run_providers)){
        $provider_title = $row_providers['course_provider'];

        $numberIncrease = 0;

echo '<div id="liSpacing"><label id="labelSearch"><input class="filter" name="provider' . ++$numberIncrease . '" type="checkbox" value="' . $provider_title . '">&nbsp;' . $provider_title . '</label></div> <br />';

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
CSS items mentioned
liSpacing:

```
#liSpacing {
  color: white;
  margin: 0em 0;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom:-5px;
```

}

Label Search:

```
#labelSearch {
    font-weight: normal;

}
```

Comment: You need to include the stylesheet that you're using. We can see references to css classes in your code, but this is a bit useless without the css itself.

This should be simple to solve with some css that keeps the text inset, while keeping the bullet point in the right place.

Comment: Try <li>s for your markup then it's just a css issue

Comment: This should only be tagged in `css`, not  in `mysql`

Comment: Ive updated my post with the css mentioned